# What is this (C/C++) program doing?

Tags: c++, winapi, cryptography, advapi32

It's calling these API functions (advapi32.dll) with these parameters:

```
CryptCreateHash ( 3275488, 32771, 0, 0, 1243424 );
CryptHashData   ( 3203040, 'UY30930037661', 13, 0 );
CryptCreateHash ( 3276304, 32771, 0, 0, 46463812 );
CryptHashData   ( 3203296, '-585164138661', 10, 0 );
CryptCreateHash ( 3276304, 32771, 0, 0, 46463808 );
CryptHashData   ( 3203424, '1db17bd8ef8bcbd734424a9eae818907LOGIN OK³·óéB', 40, 0 );
CryptCreateHash ( 3276304, 32771, 0, 0, 46463808 );
CryptHashData   ( 3203296, '1db17bd8ef8bcbd734424a9eae818907HWHASH OK', 41, 0 );
```

Not sure how it would come to

```
1db17bd8ef8bcbd734424a9eae818907
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This isn't valid C or C++ code; it uses single-quotes for string. What is the actual working code?

Comment: This isn't the source code, it's a log of API calls and their parameters from a program written in C++.

Comment: Have you checked the docs for those API calls on MSDN? If yes, what didn't you understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(see [here:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379908%28VS.85%29.aspx))
The call to CryptCreateHash initiates hashing with MD5 (32771 = 0x8003): [CALG_MD5  0x00008003 MD5 hashing algorithm.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375549%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). And the call to [CryptHashData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380202%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) hashes the second parameter (the one in quotes) using that hash object. I guess these long strings could be keys that are to be hashed before transmission over a network or something.